# When i click to open source.extension.manifest(ASP NET CORE) i got the error **an item with same key has already been added**

Tags: visual-studio-2017

can you help me to resolve this issue?

when i click to open the my ej2 core project template source.extension.manifest file, i got the error. 
 The error mentioned in image.
 [my manifest file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roCXR.png)
[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRbvb.png)

Comment: What extension is this about?

Comment: hii, ASPNET core extension

Comment: The process you are doing is still unclear to me, and I can't guess. Please expand as much as possible.